# PHP & SOAP efficieny - help with small code please

Tags: php, api, soap, performance

I connect up to a domain API and perform an **availability check on only one domain**.

- I would like to loop this 10 times, in the most efficient way to check for any changes in status
- I would like it to do the checks as quickly as possible (reduce the time between checks)
- I would like it to ouput each time it completes a check (if a multiple loop is in place it only outputs all checks once finished, in one go, rather than one at a time after each check / iteration in the loop)

Cheers!

> ```
> <?php
>
> // connection credentials and settings
> $location = 'https://TheApiServiceURL.com/';
> $wsdl = $location.'?wsdl';
> $username = 'APIuser';
> $password = 'APIpass';
>
> // include the console and client classes
> include "class_console.php";
> include "class_client.php";
>
> // create a client resource / connection
> $client = new Client($location, $wsdl, $username, $password);
>
> /**
> * Example usage and output results to screen
> */
>
> // Example #1: Check domain name availability
> print('========== consoleMethod[domainLookup] ==========<br/>');
> $client-­‐>set('domain', 'domain.com');
> $client-­‐>domainLookup();
> $client-­‐>screen($client-­‐>response());
> $client-­‐>unset('domain');
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: @Sjoerd: I need help with the following >     * I would like to loop this 10 times, in the most efficient way to check for any changes in status 
    * I would like it to do the checks as quickly as possible (reduce the time between checks) 
    * I would like it to ouput each time it completes a check (if a multiple loop is in place it only outputs all checks once finished, in one go, rather than one at a time after each check / iteration in the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled sub-strings of your code. I found the [documentation](http://www.netregistry.com.au/files/documents/support/resellers/reseller-api.pdf) - the provided code is from the examples section.

## About the  Class "Client"

This is what it says about the screen method:

```
public  function screen($var)
{
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($var);
    print '</pre>';
    return $this­‐>connection;
}
```

and

```
public function  response()
{
   return $this-­>response;
}
```

## Efficiently Looping 10 Times

If you want to get your response every iteration (is what you want, right?), do this:

```
$client‐>set('domain', 'domain.com');

$i=0;
while($i<10)
    {

        $client‐>domainLookup();
        echo $client‐>response(); 
        // or  $client‐>screen($client‐>response());            

    $i++;
    }

$client-­>unset('domain');
```

According to [this benchmark](http://www.hm2k.com/posts/for-vs-while-in-php) `while` beats `for`. But it will be a minor difference at 10 iterations. *However,* If you really do want to tweak it I suggest timing different approaches- maybe even trying to copy paste the commands 10 times.

## DomainLookup() Speed

#### Or refered to as "Checking Speed" by you.

This depends on the function `domainLookup()` which is provided by the api. So you'll have to see what this function is doing if you want to make the "checking speed" quicker. You could multi-thread the function but php isn't really made for that.